# Send and receive different types of object in netty

Tags: java, netty

I am building an application in Netty which will allow people to download and upload file. But before that they should be able to log into the server. Once they log in they can download or upload the file.

Issue I am having is how will I know the data I have received is a string(username password string) or a chunked file(as I send files as ChunkedFile) or any other java object. How will I properly get them to original form. I know we can use encoder and decoders but there are no proper example available which shows anything close to the problem I am having?

Thanks

Comment: what the problem to add a http header with the kind of file ?

Comment: Yeah I read at few places that we can add a httpheader to the data sent but I can't find any example on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a POST http request with Headers

```
   // Prepare the HTTP request.
            FullHttpRequest request = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, uriJson.toASCIIString());
          request.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

            ByteBuf  buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(data, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            request.content().writeBytes(buf);
            request.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH,request.content().readableBytes());
```

Comment: Can you also tell what encoder and decoder I need to use for HttpRequest?
Also since I will be sending a file as a chunked file and when doing so multiple messageReceived() are hit as file is send in parts, so does that mean every time I will have the filename in httpheader?

Comment: see here https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example